iOS custom keyboard highlight/coloring specific text programmatically swift
I am developing an iOS keyboard app where i need to select specific text programmatically. Suppose I want to highlight a word of a sentence on a button click(attached an image for reference).I found and tried with setMarkedText method of TextDocumentProxy. But it actually  do not meet my purpose, because it inserts the provided text whereas I need to mark the existing text.
Can anyone help me solving this issue please.

